# I wanna get list content by 4 rows

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna parse excel and make lists by 4 rows.
Now I wrote

```
book3 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)

tag_list = sheet3.row_values(0)
user_id = tag_list[9]
for row_index in range(7, sheet3.nrows):
    row = sheet3.row_values(row_index)
    print(row)
```

In print(row),it is shown

```
['', '', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M, 'N', 'O', '', '', '', '']
['', 'u1000', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '', '', '', '']
['', '500～1000', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '', '', '', '']
['', 'd500', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '', '', '', '']
・・・・・
```

Now I wanna get these lists by 4 ones like

```
[ ['', '', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M, 'N', 'O', '', '', '', '']
    ['', 'u1000', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '', '', '', '']
    ['', '500～1000', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '', '', '', '']
    ['', 'd500', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '×', '', '', '', '']]
    ・・・・・
```

To do my ideal thing,what should I write to it?How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fourrows=[] //place holder
for row_index in range(7, sheet3.nrows):
    row = sheet3.row_values(row_index)
    if len(fourrows)==4:
       print(fourrows)
       fourrows=[]
    fourrows.append(row) // I put this here as there is a chance of printing an extra empty list at the end if we've perfect four multiples.
print(fourrows)
```

`fourrows` collects rows till it is four in number.
Once it is filled with four rows it prints out all four and empties the `fourrows` list.
It continues till there are no more
Take note that the last iteration prints out any left over rows of 1/2/3 or 4.

Or the python way of doing it would be...

```
for i in range(7, sheet3.nrows,4):
   print([sheet3.row_values(row_index) for row_index in range(i, min(i+4,sheet3.nrows))])
```

Comment: Please provide a short explanation. Code only answers aren't the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with these changes. I have created on list and every row of excel file is getting appended in this list.

```
final_list = []
book3 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)

tag_list = sheet3.row_values(0)
user_id = tag_list[9]
for row_index in range(7, sheet3.nrows):
    row = sheet3.row_values(row_index)
    final_list.append(row)
print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the for loop in a more pythonic way:

```
final_list = list(
    sheet3.row_values(row_index) for
    row_index in
    range(7, sheet3.nrows)
)
print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most Pythonic way would be a list comprehension:

```
all_rows = [sheet3.row_values(row_index) for row_index in range(7, sheet3.nrows)]
```